# MySQL partitioning across different HDDs?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, innodb, partitioning

Is it possible to partition a table and locate different partitions on different hard-drives?

I have a table that will be eventually 1.5 Terabyte in size and need to split it across multiple hard-drives as it won't fit on just one.

I've tried searching the Internet but all the info seems to be outdated and pointing to the conclusion that with InnoDB it's impossible?

Comment: I'm not aware this is possible, is there no way you can reorganise it and split into different tables based on some criteria ? Hard without knowing more about the db design, but feels a little unwieldy to have it all as one table.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/lvm2faq.html#AEN407) for LVM the maximum size of a logical volume is 8EB (exabytes). The ZFS file system can handle single files up to 16EB.